# Update password hashing for existing users ASP.NET identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hash, asp.net-identity

For one of my webapps I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5. For sometime I used default password hashing algorithm. I would like now to switch to custom hasher.

But the question is: **What happens to exising data? How do I update hashes for exising users?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update hashes for existing users.

The only option really is to add a column to the database table indicating the hash method, and write code to support both the old and new hashing methods contingent on the value found in that column.

If you like, you can update each user's hash as they sign on individually (since that is the only time the site has the cleartext password available).  But there is no way to update the hashes on a batch basis whilst offline.